# How can I give CSS styles to each instance of the same dynamic component angular8

Tags: css, angular, angular8

Im new with Angular and I am creating a chat application with the same facebook behavior. I need each chat box to appear at the bottom of the screen (right now they appear in the middle of the screen) and as a user is selected the box that comes out You should leave next to the one that is already there.

I also need that when those chat boxes occupy the entire space, something similar to the image attached is shown, a button where the first boxes that you select come out so that you can select and resume that conversation. In the following link I have my application working. Could someone help me? The application code and the demo can see it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ucnueu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

The image of the behavior that I want is the following:
[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website OR off-site example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: I understand what you say but my case is particular. I did not find another way to explain my situation and what I want to achieve, and if I put a code snippet it would be very difficult for someone to understand me.Sorry for that